# Bound for the minimal vector of an indefinite lattice

Tags: integer-lattices

Let $L$ be a positive definite lattice. Then we have different bounds for the norm of the minimal vector of $L$.

But if $L$ is indefinite of determinant $\det(L)=d$ and rank $r$, does it exists a bound $M$, depending only on $d$ and $r$, on the minimum of $|\langle v,v \rangle|$ for $v\in L$?

Comment: What is a "positive definite lattice"?

Comment: A lattice can be also defined as a free abelian group equipped with a symmetric bilinear form

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: A lattice is positive definite iff it is positive definite as real bilinear form iff its intersection matrix is positive definite